# How to use custom classes in expressions like math objects?

Tags: c#, .net, matrix, operators, expression

I have noticed that it is possible to define a custom class and then use operators like +,-,/ and * on a number of them rather than using methods to do so. For example, I created a Matrix class that does complex matrix algebra/differentiation and created it so that all the operations were controlled by methods:

```
Matrix m1 = new Matrix(new double[][] { /* Some data */ });
Matrix m2 = new Matrix(new double[][] { /* Some other data */ });

// Returns a new Matrix object equal to the result
m1 = m1.Multiply(m2);
m1 = m1.Add(m2.Inverse);
m1 = m1.Subtract(m2.Determinant);
m1 = m1.ApplyToCombinator(new AlgebraMatrix(new string[][] { /* Some data *. }));
```

However, after looking at [This CodeProject Page](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/dynmatrixmath.aspx), and after using the XNA framework (`Position = Speed * (float)gameTime.ElapsedTime.TotalSeconds;` where a `Vector2` object is being multiplied by a `float` using `*`), you can use the +,-,/ and * instead.

So how would I have to change my class so I could simply type the following code to do the same as above?

```
m1 = m1 * m2 + m2.Inverse - m2.Determinant;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

MSDN: [Operator overloading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467(VS.71).aspx)

```
public static Matrix operator +(Matrix mat)
{
    //do stuff  
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea what it was called!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need to look at [Operator Overloading.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467(VS.71).aspx) Also see [this tutorial](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/Lesson18.aspx). Have fun :)